# two nodes in cassandra are not gossiping to each other

Tags: cassandra, gossip

Node0:
configuration.yaml file:
cluster_name: 'ServerCluster' 
num_tokens: 256
Seeds: "" 
listen_address: 10.104.0.15
rpc_address: 10.104.0.15
auto_bootstrap: false
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

cassandra-env.sh file : JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -java.rmi.server.hostname=10.104.0.15"
cassandra-rackdc file: dc=DC1rack=RAC1

Node1:
configuration.yaml file:
cluster_name: 'ServerCluster' 
num_tokens: 256
Seeds: "10.104.0.15" 
listen_address: 10.104.0.20 
rpc_address: 10.104.0.20
auto_bootstrap: true
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

cassandra-env.sh file : JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.104.0.20"
cassandra-rackdc file: dc=DC1rack=RAC1

Node0 is up and fine 
Node1 error:

```
INFO  00:03:44 OutboundTcpConnection using coalescing strategy DISABLED
INFO  00:03:45 Handshaking version with /10.104.0.15
ERROR 00:04:16 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1333) ~
[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision
(StorageService.java:540) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageServ
ice.java:788) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:720) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:611) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.ja
va:387) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon
.java:562) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.jav
a:651) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1333)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision
(StorageService.java:540)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageServ
ice.java:788)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:720)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:611)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.ja
va:387)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon
.java:562)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.jav
a:651)
Exception encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any seeds
WARN  00:04:16 No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing     shu
```

tdown
    INFO  00:04:16 Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
    INFO  00:04:16 MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread

Then I changed the seeds(because saw a solution in stackoverflow) for
Node0:
Seeds: "10.104.0.15,10.104.0.20" 
Node1:
Seeds: "10.104.0.20" 

Node0 is fine 
Node1 error:

```
INFO  00:25:36 Thrift API version: 19.39.0
INFO  00:25:36 CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.2.1 (default: 3.2.1)
INFO  00:25:36 Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of    101
MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
INFO  00:25:36 Loading persisted ring state
ERROR 00:25:36 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:
66) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:718) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:611) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.ja
va:387) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon
.java:562) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.jav
a:651) [apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:
66)
    at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:718)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:611)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.ja
 va:387)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon
.java:562)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.jav
a:651)
Exception encountered during startup: Shutdown in progress
```

So can you help me to get out this chicken and egg problem?
Than you in advance

even I followed the datastax link https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds210-datastax-enterprise-operations-and-performance-tuning/multiple-data-centers-multiple-0

where he just changes the clustername,listen_address, rpc_address and seeds and when he types nodetool status he was able to see both of them but when i follow the same I see only its status in it respective server

Comment: What ports have you opened?

Comment: Hi Jon, before opening any ports I thought to stop the windows firewall service now they are communicating so are there any specific ports to be opened? and thank you so much for that question I read everywhere but nobody said a word about port thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop both nodes.  Delete the data folder.   Change the config to have both nodes as seeds.  Start each node again.  I suspect there may be some weirdness from the first failed try.

Here's a list of all the ports that need to be open, make sure you can reach them (use telnet to check).

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureFireWall_r.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will resolve your issue. But it is a good advice.

**All the nodes should have the same seeds and you should have at least one seed by datacenter.** Even if the only seed of one node is itself.

If I was you I would try this settings on all nodes :

```
seeds: "10.104.0.15, 10.104.0.20"
```

And I do not understand why you did not specify any dc, rack for node 1. Is it intentional ?

Comment: I forgot to mention the rack-dc properties for node1 and Even I tried giving the two ip's in the seeds the both nodes are up and running fine but not gossiping and the below is the error I get<br/>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
        at     java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:
66) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService
.java:718) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.10.jar:2.1.10]